# What is the first instance of a pink armored military vehicle in a SciFi movie?

Tags: movie, history-of, vehicles

What is the first instance of a red or pink armored military vehicle in a SciFi-ish movie?

**Background of why I asked**:

In 2008, a famous Russian director released a movie "[The Inhabited Island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inhabited_Island)", based on one of the books by Strugatsky Brothers.

The movie was a commercial flop, despite being one of the biggest SciFi projects of modern russian cinema. While some critics liked it, others ridiculed it.

One of the particular items of ridicule (especially of the memetic internet type, but also [real pranks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pH-tSBBj0v4&feature=player_embedded)) was the inclusion of a "pink colored tank". Despite the fact that the actual tank in the movie was red and not pink (pink was an artifact of the original reviewer using extremely poor quality bootlegged preview), everyone made fun of it as a symbol of a crappy movie.

[image] - Do. Not. Ask.

However, I've seen some people claim that the idea of a red/pink colored military vehicle is a perfectly fine one, **and was (like many other visuals in this movie) stolen from a western Sci-Fi work.**

However, I was never able to figure out just WHICH work it was supposed to have been stolen from? "Tank Girl" seemed the most likely, but the tank there was not red/pink.

**So, was that claim accurate, and if so, which Sci-Fi movie did the director "borrow" the idea from?**

Comment: P.S. I'm aware of pink/red vehicles IRL (e.g. Pink tank monument in Prague, or Red Baron's plane, or [Mountbatten pink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountbatten_pink) of British ships). The claim was specifically about some SciFi movie.

Comment: additionally - the Long Range Desert Group used a pink paint as camoflauge in North Africain WWII. This continued long after the war.

Comment: @HorusKol - True. IIRC the story goes that they got the idea directly from Mountbatten, which is why I didn't include them in the list :) I should ask on History SE

Comment: There were a number of pink Spitfires used by the British for reconnaissance back in WWII as well, as it gave a camouflage advantage.  http://io9.com/5872484/why-world-war-ii-spy-planes-used-pink-camouflage

Comment: forgot to mention that the Land Rovers (after the war) became known as "Pink Panthers" :)

Comment: Not precisely a pink tank, nor a movie, but in Vernor Vinge's *The Peace War* the American directorate of the The Peace Authority paints it's vehicles in a paisley patter.

Comment: There was a tank painted pink as part of the *[Velvet Revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monument_to_Soviet_tank_crews)*, but that was art not sci-fi

Comment: Are you asking about the first instance of this idea in sci-fi, as per your title (in which case, maybe add the [tag:history-of] tag), or specifically about where *The Inhabited Island* got their idea from, as per your question body (in which case, maybe add the [tag:inspiration] tag)?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - of WoG exists, the latter. As that's extremely unlikely, the former.

Comment: @DVK OK, I edited the tags - hope you don't mind :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I've not actually seen the movie - or heard of it until I found it by googling "pink tank sci fi film" BUT a 1987 Canadian film "[The Pink Chiquitas](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093741/)" did, apparently, have a pink tank in it.

The following is a quote from the plot synopsis from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pink_Chiquitas) for the film.

> After placing Mary Ann in the town jail, Tony and Clip go back into the woods and track the meteor to a cave. They escape a group of women who arrive to worship it, but their effort to drive to the next town for help is frustrated by a roadblock. They return to Beamsville to find that the women's takeover of the town is complete, with the remaining men wandering the streets in dazed stupors. Clip attempts to discover how to defeat the meteor by experimenting on the fragment he possesses, but is overcome by the fumes produced after accidentally setting it on fire. Tony is also subdued by a group of women in a **pink Sherman tank**, who knock him unconscious when they blast apart the town jail where he takes refuge.

I've looked, briefly, for a screenshot of the tank in question but I can't find one. Unfortunately, I'm not willing to actually watch the film to get a screenshot either seeing as this film sounds really quite bad.

While the film is Sci-fi, I have no idea if the director saw the film and took the idea of a pink/red tank or not. BUT, this is the only Sci-Fi film I've found that has a red/pink coloured tank.

Comment: Smaller than a submarine, but you've got the SciFi right. +1

Answer (score 6):

Military, technically a vehicle, technically armored, and pink:
[Operation Petticoat](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053143/) (1959):

> World War 2 comedy about a submarine commander who finds himself stuck with a decrepit (and pink) sub, a con-man executive officer and a group of army nurses.

-Not Sci-fi.

[Kelly's Heroes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065938/reviews) (1970). Tank is not pink, but it does fire pink paint shells at panzers.

-Also Not Sci-fi.

Comment: I will postpone acceptance since I'm assuming there's a SciFi answer as the claim stated. But if no better sources to steal from appear, this will be it.

Answer (score 1):

Pink tanks are kind of a [Russian thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monument_to_Soviet_tank_crews#Controversy_and_the_artistic_response), which seems a more likely origin for the critiques remarks.

Comment: Yeah, but this was (1) Chech thing, not Russian thing; and (2) Nothing to do with a SciFi movie

Comment: The tanks are however Russian. And no, nothing to do with sci-fi. But this is the only thing I can find about pink tanks that might fit, even if its not what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it was in any movie, but Imperial Guard tanks in Warhammer 40k are painted red as part of Mars camo scheme.